# Trying to make a method that shows the guessed letters for the game Hang Man (Java)

Tags: java

I want to make it so that every time `hiddenWord();` is called it shows a hint of the word depending on the guessed letters that were attempted, so without guesses you will get something like this `"____"` and if the word was for example Mike and I guessed 'i' and 'e' it would show `"_i_e"`.
I've been at this for quite a while and I just can't wrap my head around it. I'm still a newbie so sorry in advance if the problem was something very basic.

I'll post the method I'm trying to make without the rest of the program, if needed I can post the rest. I have two main problems with this method.

1- I need to have `this.guessedLetter` have at least 3 chars in it, so in it's current state which is "" it won't work. That's why added 3 spaces to it below. Or else I'll get an index error that I don't understand.

2- The second issue is how to properly distribute the `"_"` when I don't find the letter, I seem to be doing way too many dashes.

```
public String hiddenWord() {
        int i = 1;
        int j = 1;
        this.guessedLetters += "  ";
        char c = this.word.charAt(i);
        char d = this.guessedLetters.charAt(j);
        while (i <= this.guessedLetters.length()-1) {
           while (j <= this.word.length()-1) {
               if (c == d) {
                   this.hiddenWord += c;
                   j++;
               }
               else {
                   this.hiddenWord += "_";
                   j++;
               }              
           }
           i++;
        }
        return this.hiddenWord;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. The indices should start at 0, not 1. 2. You need to reset j for each iteration of i. 3. c needs to be looked up when i changes, and likewise d when j changes. They will only be affected by values of i and j at the time they are assigned. 4. You should iterate over the length of the word in the outer loop and the guessed letters in the inner loop. 5. You could probably find an alternative solution using the STring replace() or replaceAll() functions

Comment: A user can only guess 1 letter at a time?

Comment: Yes. Only 1 letter at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a little class for you. I wrote it based on what I could deduce from your description.

```
public class Hangman {
    // This char array will hold the result after each guess
    // for example, if the word is "mike", and the use guesses 'i'
    // the result array will contain ['_', 'i', '_', '_']
    private char[] result = null;

    // The word the user has to guess
    private String word = null;

    public Hangman(String word) {
        this.word = word;
        result = new char[word.length()];
        // initialize the result to contain only underscores
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
            result[i] = '_';
    }

    public String getResult(char guessChar) {
        // The underlying char array of the secret word
        char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
            if (wordArray[i] == guessChar)
                result[i] = guessChar;
        }
        return new String(result);
    }
}
```

Here is an usage example of the above class

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hangman h = new Hangman("mike");
        System.out.println(h.getResult('i')); // prints _i__
        System.out.println(h.getResult('e')); // prints _i_e

    }
}
```